# Asymptotic expansion as $r\to 0^+$ for $ (2re^r -3(e^r-1))^2 $ using small o

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

I need to find and asymptotic expresion as $r\to 0^+$ for  $ (2re^r -3(e^r-1))^2 $

1)First I work with the base:

$2re^r -3(e^r-1) =2r(1+r+o(r))-3(1+r+o(r)-1) =2r +2r^2 + ro(r)-3r-3o(r)=-r+2r^2 +ro(r)-3o(r)$

**I am not sure how to deal with the $ro(r)-3o(r)$ part.**

Should it be  $-r+2r^2 +ro(r)-3o(r) = -r+2r^2 +o(r)-3o(r)=-r + o(r)$  ?...(1) ,

where in the last equality $2r^2=o(r)$, so it got absorved , $o(r) -3o(r)=o(r)$ and $ro(r)=o(r)$ since if something is small with respect to $r$ (as $r$ goes to $0$) , that is $o(r)$, like $r^2$, after multiplying by $r$, $ro(r)$ it is still small with respect to $r$, so it is $o(r)$

**OR** should it be  $-r+2r^2 +ro(r)-3o(r) = -r+2r^2 +o(r^2)-3o(r)=-r +2r^2 + o(r^2) $ ?...(2), where $ ro(r)=o(r^2)$ since if something is small with respect to $r$ (as $r$ goes to $0$) , that is $o(r)$, like $r^2$, after multiplying by $r$, $ro(r)$ it is  small with respect to $r^2$, so it is $o(r^2)$

**So is this a correct second order expansion? can this simplify to (1)?**

2. now for the square, assuming I use (1),
   $(2re^r -3(e^r-1))^2=(-r + o(r))^2$ and now  I am unsure if it must be

$(-r + o(r))^2 = r^2+o(r)o(r)+2(-r)o(r)=r^2 + o(r^2)$ , since $o(r)o(r)=o(r^2)$ and $ro(r)=o(r^2) $

**OR** since I have seen examples where they just don't touch the o(r) at every step, be it composition, divisin, multiplication or exponentiation ( see the picture below):

$r^2 +o(r)$, but in that case $r^2=o(r)$ and it yields $r^2 +o(r)=o(r)+o(r)=o(r)$

**can someone clear this up to me?**

Edit: Example picture
[image: )]

Answer (score 1):

Take your initial expansions out a little further: $2re^r = 2r+2r^2+r^3+O(r^4)$ and $3(e^r-1) = 3r+3r^2/2+r^3/2+O(r^4)$;  you now get $2re^r-3(e^r-1) = -r+r^2/2-r^3/2+O(r^4)=-r+r^2/2+O(r^3)=-r+O(r^2)$.

The square of this will be $r^2+rO(r^2)+O(r^4) = r^2+O(r^3) =r^2+o(r^2)$.

Comment: Why is it that when taking powers, the small o is untouched, like in the picture I just uploaded at the end of the post?

Comment: Taking $(x-x^2/2+x^3/3+o(x^3))^2$ as an example, you have the square equal to $x^2-x^3+11x^4/12-x^5/3+x^6/9+o(x^4)$; the $o(x^4)$ because $o(x^3)$ times any of $x, x^2, x^3,\ldots$ is $o(x^4)$. Therefore the square is equal to $x^2-x^3+11x^4/12+o(x^4)=x^2-x^3+o(x^3)$.